# push notification is not working on device

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Hi I’m trying to create push notification in my app I’m getting device token and php script I have written by see some tutorials but now I’m not getting the push notification in my device not don’t where I have done wrong here please help me out..

this is my php script ...

```
<?php

   if($_POST['message']){

   $deviceToken ='here i have given my device token ';

   $message = stripcslashes($_POST['message']);

    $payload = '{
         "aps" :
      {
      "alert" :"'.$message.'",
      "badge" : 1,
      "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
     }  
    }';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl', 'local_cert','ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl','passphrase', 'bali');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',$err,$errstr,60,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$ctx);
   if(!fp){
       print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
       return;
       }else{
            print "notifications sent!";
           }
             $devArray = array();
             $devArray[] = $deviceToken;

             foreach($devArray as $deviceToken){
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack("H", str_replace(' ',' ',$deviceToken)).pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        print "sending message:" .$payload . "n";
        fwrite($fp,$msg);
       }
           fclose($fp);
       }

      ?>
```

i worte this script using this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3YlqWWnI6s)

using this php script im trying to run on my local host but not working pls tell where im doing wrong in the script

thanks.

Comment: have u allowed push notifications for you applications on you device?

Answer (score 1):

hi guys i figured out where i was wrong

```
pack("H*", str_replace(' ',' ',$deviceToken)).
```

in my about code  the  asterisk symbol was missing near h after putting asterisk its working fine for me

thanks for ur replays

Answer (score 0):

server should provide some error/success response, read answer from socket before closing it, also check connection error.